# Лишние символы в начале XML-файла

Tags: python, ubuntu, xml, кодировка, utf-8

Хочу распарсить XML-файл. После скачивания вижу в начале файла какие-то лишние символы. При чем это происходит только с локального компьютера (на Ubuntu). Если этот же скрипт закинуть на сервер (тоже на Ubuntu), то все ок.

Что это такое и что с этим делать?

```py
xml = requests.get(url).text.encode('utf-8')
print(xml[:10])
```

Результат такой:

```
b'\xc3\xaf\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbf<?xm'
```

Без encode эти символы выглядят как `ï»¿`

Comment: как вы впоследствии планируете парсить XML?

Comment: @MaxU через BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ï»¿` в начале файла обычно является [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) сигнатурой.

В этом случае следует воспользоваться кодировкой `utf-8-sig` (как указано в вашем ответе):

```
r = requests.get(url)
if not r.ok:
    r.raise_for_status()
xml = r.content.decode('utf-8-sig')
```

`.content` в отличие от `.text` вернет байт-строку, которую можно декодировать, используя нужную кодировку.

Answer (score 3):

Помогло сделать вот так

```py
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
xml = r.text
```